# Polarity of fuse? Amptrap A30QS500-4

Tags: fuses

Could someone explain reason behind diode pictogram (symbol) on an Amptrap A30QS500-4 fuse?

- Why would a fuse have polarity, does it?
- How can I find the polarity of it? I tried to check it with multimeter and it buzzes on both orientations.

[image]

Comment: If one side of the fuse is electrically connected to those metal studs on the case, perhaps that side should be the one downstream of the power supply? I don't have an answer, though, just a guess.

Comment: @user505160: I do not think that marking indicates there's a diode in the fuse.  The [datasheet](https://ep-us.mersen.com/sites/mersen_us/files/DS-A30QS-Amp-Trap-Form-101-Mersen.pdf) indicates that this model is used to protect high current semiconductors, so the markings might indicate that.  I don't think so, though.

Comment: Many years ago, I worked with a guy who was an electrician in the United States Air Force.  He told me a (mildly funny) story involving Amptrap fuses. It used to be a tradition to play pranks on the new guy in a department - like sending someone to beans from the Beano locker or pick up 50 feet of flight line.  For the electricians, it was the Amptrap.  When a fuse kept blowing, they'd send the newbie to get an Amptrap to soak up all the extra current.  That was funny until one day they got a guy who had been an electrician before joining the Air Force. (Continued...)

Comment: Usually, the newbie would go back to the shop and ask for an Amptrap and be sent all over the place looking for one.  This one guy, though, knew that there were real fuses named Amptraps.  He went out and got a real Amptrap and brought it to the job site.  That pretty much ended **that** joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you learn something new everyday.

The symbol means it is a fuse intended to protect semiconductors.

From page 5 of this [Eaton *Protecting semiconductors with  high speed fuses* application guide:](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electrical-circuit-protection/fuses/bussmann-series-high-speed-fuses/bus-ele-an-10507-hsf.pdf)

[image]

The fuse you have is definitely a semiconductor protection fuse.  The [Amptrap A30QS500-4 datasheet](https://ep-us.mersen.com/sites/mersen_us/files/DS-A30QS-Amp-Trap-Form-101-Mersen.pdf) is clear on that point:

> A30QS Amp-Trap® high speed fuses are intended for the protection of Power Semiconductors such as diodes, phase control SCRs and other power semiconductor devices. The A30QS is recommended for new applications providing solutions for your critical protection needs at 300V and less semiconductors.

The ["aR" indicates what specific task the fuse is for:](https://www.swe-check.com.au/editorials/semiconductor_fuse_classes.php)

> aR class fuses only provide partial-range breaking capacity (short-circuit protection only) for the protection of power semiconductors (IEC Utilization category). Note: aR fuses are often faster (with a lower I²t value) than a comparable gS or gR fuse. An aR class fuse must not be used as a replacement for a gR class fuse.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow runs perpendicular to the body of the device, so I don't think it indicates a polarity.

Besides, the specs indicate a VAC as well as an VDC rating, so it must be able to pass current in both directions.